# Why does the file size decrease after encryption using an offset cipher?

Tags: c, file, encryption, file-io

I encrypted a text file using an offset cipher in C. For this, I simply added 128 to each character and got the file size decreased by 3 bytes. I tried the same on some other files too just to get the same result, i.e. decrease in file size by 3 bytes. I got the original size after decryption.

Could you please tell me why does it so happen?

Code for the main logic is given below:

```
while((ch=fgetc(fs))!=EOF){
         fputc(ch+128, ft);
```

Comment: The file size shouldn't double, you're not storing twice the information, just changing the information stored in each byte. However, the file size *should* be the same, so I'm not sure why you're missing three bytes.

Comment: `fputc` always puts one character ie 1 byte. However even I'm not sure why the size increase. Probably the file contains four EOF at the end of the file :p

Comment: Have you pulled the flush when you was done? Or just exited?

Comment: "two bytes were taken for one character after encryption as something greater than 127 can not be stored in 1 byte" -- You might want to explain further why you think this, because it's quite wrong and that you think it suggests that you have one or more serious misconceptions.

Comment: @loxxy I tried it on some other files too, but the same thing happened. By incrementing characters by 128 file size increased by 3 bytes, and the original file size was regained after decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you talk about Windows, I could imagine that you have opened the file in text mode, not in binary mode.

That leads to the following:

- Writing `\n` leads to a `\r\n` written to the file.
- Reading `\r\n` from the file gives only `\n` to the user.
- Reading stops at the first `\x1A`, being a EOF character.

If you add 128 to each byte, the data-to-be-written rolls over at 256. While it may be undefined behaviour to call `fputc()` with a value > 256 (you should write `(ch+128)%256` or `(ch+128) & 0xFF`), on your systems it obviously writes the value wrapped by 256 and thus you may get `\n` or `\x1A` by accident.

Answer (score 3):

> Could you please tell me why does it so happen?

Your `ch` probably has the wrong declaration.  The `fputc()` function returns an `int`, not a `char`, and if you cast to `char` you will lose the distinction between `(char) 0xff` and `EOF`.

```
// WRONG WRONG WRONG
// char ch = fgetc(fs);
```

The right declaration:

```
int ch = fgetc(fs);
```

Otherwise, it shouldn't happen.  Is your process exiting cleanly?  If you `abort()`, then there might be data still in `FILE *` buffers.  Show more code.  Run with Valgrind.  Check the exit status of your process.

> I think the file size should have doubled as two bytes were taken for one character after encryption as something greater than 127 can not be stored in 1 byte.

No, `fputc()` does not work that way.  The `fputc()` man page (run `man fputc` in a terminal, unless on Windows):

> `fputc()` writes the character `c`, cast to an `unsigned char`, to `stream`.

Conversion to `unsigned char` is done by taking the value modulo 256<sup>*</sup>.  So `fputc()` always writes exactly one byte of data (unlesss it fails).

<sup>*</sup> This is true all but exceedingly rare systems.

Comment: thanks for ur kind response. Before I could ask further, I am quite unfamiliar with what you have written with EOF, or its numbering system. what is 0xff? . Could you plz provide me any relevant link?

Comment: `0xff` is hexadecimal.  It's the same as 255.